# Does the word "like" take the meaning of "to the extent of"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

I know the preposition *like* means "in the same way as". But, can it also mean "to the extent of"? Say for example,

> I love editing like I love my wife.

Comment: I suppose you can pick any aspect for comparison (*extent* being one of them), but your example would tend to be read as a comparison of *manner* rather than *extent*.

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence. But if you were to write this sentence to be read as a comparison of extent, how would you rephrase it as? Just to stress "I love my wife" more than anything, and editing comes closer to it.

Comment: "I love editing almost as much as I love my wife."

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan Tusar Raj has hit the nail on the head: make the comparison explicitly about extent with "as much as".

Comment: 'In the way that' is really the synonym, but this often corresponds to 'to the extent that'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [American Heritage's usage note](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/like) on the conjunction definition of *like*:

> Usage Note: They don't make them like they used to. I remember it like it was yesterday. As these familiar examples show, like is often used as a conjunction meaning "as" or "as if," particularly in speech. While writers since Chaucer's time have used like as a conjunction, the usage today has a somewhat informal or conversational flavor. Language critics and writing handbooks have condemned the conjunctive use of like for more than a century, and in accordance with this tradition, like is usually edited out of more formal prose. This is easy enough to do, since as and as if stand as synonyms: Sales of new models rose as (not like) we expected them to. He ran as if (not like) his life depended on it. · Like is acceptable at all levels as a conjunction when used with verbs such as feel, look, seem, sound, and taste: It looks like we are in for a rough winter. Constructions in which the verb is not expressed, such as He took to politics like a duck to water, are also acceptable, especially since in these cases like can be viewed as a preposition.